# How can I get a list of all accounts, contracts, and tokens?

Tags: cleos, accounts

`cleos` doesn't have a subcommand for this.

Comment: eosio version: Dawn 4.0

Answer (score 1):

It may be worthwhile looking at some of the EOStracker code developed here https://github.com/EOSEssentials/EOSTracker

That uses a mongodb interface and the running examples did show accounts and transactions.

Not sure if this is still working on Dawn 4 though

Comment: unfortunately mongodb plugin is crashing the Dawn 4 build... it's an excellent question though because I also want to know how to do that without mongo...